# Showing two temp tables data in a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one temp table having data like below in sql server

**Table 1**

```
**Data** 
ISD-I987330
PSD-I987330
KSD-I987330
JSD-I987330
RSD-I987330
QSD-I987330
QSD-I987359
```

And another temp table having data like below

**Table 2**

```
**Data**
BRA-22310
BRA-22319
BRA-22316
BRA-22313
BRA-22317
```

I am trying to display both these tables data in a single table.Like below

[image]

But I am getting cross joins data.

Below is my query

```
declare @TempResults table
(


    Tickets1    varchar(50),  
    Tickets2    varchar(50)
)

insert into @TempResults 
Select distinct ti.Tickets1,
tr.Tickets2
FROM @Table1 ti,@table2 tr

select * from  @TempResults
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't really get the output you want without each table having a separate column which maintains the *order* of each record, in each table.  Absent that, we could use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate an order, and then join:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT Data, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Data) rn
    FROM Table1
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Data, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Data) rn
    FROM Table2
)

SELECT
    t1.Data,
    t2.Data
FROM cte1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

Comment: Do I need to declare this variables ?                                                                  declare @TempResults table (

    Tickets1    varchar(50),  
    Tickets2    varchar(50)
)

Comment: You should be able to insert into your temp table using the select query I gave above in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can join using `row_number()`

```
  with cte1 as 
    (select *,row_number() over(order by data) rn
    from table1
    ),
    cte2 as
    (
    select *,row_number() over(order by data) rn
    ) select cte1.data,cte2.data from cte1 left join ct2 on cte1.rn=cte2.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution but not necessarily the best, is to make the union of tables in a temporary table with different names for each of the columns

```
select * Into @TempResults  From
(
   SELECT  ti.Tickets1 as 'Tickets1',' ' as 'Tickets2'
   FROM @Table1 ti
   UNION
   SELECT ' ' as 'Tickets1',  tr.Tickets2 as 'Tickets2'
   FROM @table2 tr
) T
```